# What topical applications can assist wound healing and prevent scarring?

Tags: wound, wound-care

I have used vitamin E to help prevent scarring.  Are there any other topical applications that can assist wound healing and prevent scarring?

Comment: Are you interested in therapies as well?

Answer (score 6):

It greatly depends on the wound: is it clean or infected? A cut on an abrasion? Acute or chronic. Associated with disease (diabetes), immobility (pressure) or other? Is it a burn?

Honey is often overlooked. It is an antibacterial and a humectant, both helping wounds to heal better. Epidermal growth factor also helps but is not easy to get. Silver is preferred for burns (nanosilver is making an appearance). Collagen gels and other topicals are helpful. The body of literature is huge.

I like an ointment with lanolin and allantoin, both of which promote healing.

<sub>[Honey: A Potent Agent for Wound Healing?](http://journals.lww.com/jwocnonline/Abstract/2002/11000/Honey__A_Potent_Agent_for_Wound_Healing_.8.aspx)</sub>
<sub>[Wound healing dressings and drug delivery systems: A review](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jps.21210/full)</sub>
<sub>[Topical treatments for hypertrophic scars](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0190962206008279)</sub>
<sub>[Systematic review of the use of honey as a wound dressing](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1472-6882/1/2)</sub>

Comment: You decided to come join the club. I read your response in chat but haven't replied yet.

Answer (score -4):

There are many treatments that claim to reduce and improve the look of scars, however if they work, it's another thing.

You may find here [Daily Mail reviews of various treatments](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-1319735/How-make-scar-vanish-There-host-treatments-work.html), however remember, you should always talk to your surgeon or doctor before starting a treatment.

---

Here are my cherry picks:

- **Silicone patches** are effective over a wound which seems to help a scar to heal better.
- **Aloe vera gel** on the skin and Vitamin E cream as you suggested.

---

#### Alternative medicine.

Please don't expect any miracles here.

- [therapeutic ultrasound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therapeutic_ultrasound)

  There are three primary benefits to ultrasound:

  1. Speeding up of the healing process from the increase in blood flow in the treated area.
  2. Decrease in pain from the reduction of swelling and edema.
  3. Gentle massage of muscles tendons and/ or ligaments in the treated area because no strain is added and any scar tissue is softened.

  If the scar is old, it may trigger natural healing by increasing local blood flow.
- [infrared sauna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_sauna) (alternative to Sun)

  This therapy which can assist with wound healing by deep penetrating heat human tissue and increased blood delivery to the surface of the skin which can speed up healing.
- dermatological roller

  You may also try dermatological roller which simply is damaging old skin tissue in order to re-heal.
- C60/EVOO (C60 in Extra Virgin Olive Oil)

  C60/EVOO is an strong anti-oxidant at intracellular level which results in better functioning mitochondria.

  [Studies](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/24021223_Fullerene_nanomaterials_potentiate_hair_g%20rowth/links/0c960528b84a79db7e000000.pdf) in 2009 showed that fullerene nanomaterials potentiate hair growth:

  > In SKH-1hairless mice fullerene derivatives given **topically** or subdermally markedly increased hair growth. This was paralleled by a significant increase in the number of hair follicles in fullerene-treated mice as compared with those mice treated with vehicle only. The fullerenes also **increased hair growth in human skin sections** maintained in culture. These studies have wide-ranging implications for those conditions leading to hair loss, including alopecia, chemotherapy, and reactions to various chemicals.
  >
  > [...] **We report that fullerene derivatives accelerate the growth of hair in mice and human skin.** [...]

  Dr. Moussa has studied the effects of C60 on animals for 18 years and claim C60 in olive oil is safe and anti-toxic (has no toxicity effects).

  One [researcher](http://www.longecity.org/forum/user/19769-turnbuckle/) who was/is taking C60-EVOO orally/topically for over 3 years, claims:

  > More youthful skin. Skin pinch test went from 1-2 seconds to 0 seconds. (I had very youthful skin to begin with).
  >   Two small scars from 8 years ago have disappeared. Two similar scars of much older vintage did not.
  >   Strengthening of nails, hair regrowth, and the disappearance of small scars that I have observed from my own use could be the result of stem cell action.

  However based on my experience, it could work differently on different people, but it's worth to try just topically (e.g. before dermarolling skin).

Comment: The Daily Mail is a disreputable paper, with many unsubstantiated health claims in articles. Just wanted to point that out. Also, while true scars do undergo remodeling, *nothing, but nothing*, can make them disappear.

Comment: Your only scientifically-backed source here pertains to hair-growth. You have no evidence supporting your other claims. Additionally, longcity and researchgate are both broken links, making your total reliable sources 0.